310 Volt Brushless DC Motor Advantages
What are the advantages/disadvantages of 310 VDC motors used in small household electronics such as fans and air conditioners? Why use such high (dangerous?) voltage in these motors instead of a more typical 12/24/48 volts? Are these motors more efficient, less noisy, provide more torque for larger sized impellers than their lower voltage counterparts?

Three factors. This eliminates a DC-DC power supply and simply rectifies AC to DC power for the BLDC motor controller, the FET costs are lower with lower current being more significant than higher voltage and less copper costs in the motor.
FET switch costs rise with current more than voltage on this range, so cost reductions that do not require any AC DC converter for DC motor result in the best bang for the buck.
Power supply costs for a 500 W motor in LVDC might add cost to the motor in Cu windings as well as ACDC converter @ <10W/$ cost combined.

Help me understand why an ac-dc power supply wouldnt be needed here. How do you convert a typical 120vac input power supply in North America to 310vdc?

@Josh voltage-doubling rectifier. For one half-cycle, the +170 V peak charges the positive output capacitor. For the -170 V half cycle, it charges the negative output capacitor. Take the output differentially from the two capacitors.

@Neil_UK I'm pretty sure that still counts as an AC-DC converter. A very basic one, but it still converts AC to DC.

@Hearth for the prompt to clarify what I assumed


What are the advantages/disadvantages of 310 VDC

To get this voltage from mains in the US takes 4 diodes (full bridge rectifier) and a capacitor. You can draw 10A from that simple circuit, and it costs roughly about the same whether it's designed for 1A or 10A.
To get 12/24/48V takes a transformer - whether in a switching power supply, or a traditional 50/60Hz mains transformer. The cost of the transformer goes up with power needed. A 500VA DC supply at such a low voltage costs orders of magnitude more than the capacitor-rectifier for HV DC.
Just look at the 100-200W power supply for a modern high-performance laptop. They are not small and they are not cheap, even though they are cost-effective - you get good performance for the price. But they have the HV DC circuit in them as well. So everything past the PFC or rectifier is added cost.
PFC is an active rectifier that makes the post-rectifier capacitor load appear like a resistive load. That's better for the energy distribution network, and is required in many markets for supplies past a certain watt rating.

A typical 310V DC brushless motor is an assembly containing a brushless motor and a control circuit. You have to provide it roughly 310V, and the control circuit figures it out. It is common that these assemblies route out 3 wires (TACH(out), PWN(in) and POWER(out)) for connecting to a control circuit. GND is typically used for both the negative of 310V and the negative of the circuit. An example of the internals of one of those motors can be found here.
The advantage of these units is that they are cheaper as they require less copper in the motor, because they generate an high frequency drive signal.
Driving these fans is also easy. In 230V countries you just use a full bridge rectifier and a capacitor, while in 110V countries you use a full bridge rectifier with a capacitor between neutral and positive and a capacitor between neutral and negative. If you want a control board with a fan speed control, because the fact that the fan assembly gives you a low voltage signal back, it is easy to just connect it to a microcontroller for a fancy display.
If you compare this to older control styles, that used a brushed universal motor, when making a control board, you required real clunking switches to handle the inductive load of the stator winding.
Note that the circuit in the motor and the motor itself needs cooling. These assemblies typically use the output of the motor to provide cooling as it runs.

"you required real clunking switches to handle the inductive load of the stator winding." - Nope.  It takes a good MOSFET, but no clunking switch.  It does, however, require a snubber to protect the MOSFET.
